# Background image for activityIndicatorView

Tags: iphone, xcode, android-activity, uiactivityindicatorview

So, I am creating the activityIndicator programmatically. All works fine. Now I want to add a background image for the Indicator and center it in the middle of the view. Any idea how to achive that?

Here's my code:

```
- (void) indicatorViewShow: (bool)show {

    if (show) {
        //--- create layout rect
        CGRect indicatorRect;
        indicatorRect.origin = self.view.center;
        indicatorRect.size.width  = 50;
        indicatorRect.size.height = 50;

        indicatorRect.origin.x -= indicatorRect.size.width / 2;

        //--- create indicator view
        indicatorView = [[IndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame: indicatorRect];

        indicatorView.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
        [indicatorView startAnimating];
        [self.view addSubview: indicatorView];

        //--- show network activity
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    } else {
        //--- hide network activity
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        [indicatorView stopAnimating];
        //--- remove indicator view
        indicatorView.hidden = YES;
        [indicatorView release];
        indicatorView = nil;
    }

}
```

Comment: The background image is the the `self.view` for that particular view. Do you want to change that ?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but if you want a good looking open source loading indicator you might want to check out DSActivityView: http://www.dejal.com/developer/dsactivityview

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass UIActivityIndicator, add a UIImageView in that class, and then you have an Activity Indicator with a background image property